Cesàro Summation
I was working on a problem regarding Cesàro summation. I was wondering if my proof is sufficient, needed to add something or wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!
Question: Let $(x_n)$ be convergent sequence of real numbers and let $y_n$ be the algebraic mean of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ i.e. $y_n=\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Prove that $(y_n)$ converges and that $\lim(y_n)=\lim(x_n)$. 
Hint: Let $x:=\lim(x_n)$. Then $\displaystyle \left|\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}-x\right|=\left|\frac{(x_1-x)+\cdots+(x_n-x)}{n}\right|$
My Solution: Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $(x_n)$ is convergent, we can define $x:=\lim(x_n)$. Additionally, if $\lim(x_n)=x\implies \exists N\forall n\geq N: |x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. Then,
$$|y_n-x|=\left|\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}-x\right|=\left|\frac{(x_1-x)+\cdots+(x_n-x)}{n}\right|=\frac{\left|(x_1-x)+\cdots+(x_n-x)\right|}{n}
            \leq\frac{\overbrace{\left|x_1-x\right|}^{<\varepsilon}+\cdots+\overbrace{\left|x_n-x\right|}^{<\varepsilon}}{n}
            <\frac{\overbrace{\varepsilon+\cdots+\varepsilon}^{n\text{ times}}}{n}
            =\frac{n\varepsilon}{n}=\varepsilon$$
Thus, $\exists N\forall n\geq N: $ $$|y_n-x|<\varepsilon\implies\lim(y_n)=x=\lim(x_n)$$ $\therefore \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, y_n$ converges and its limit is the same as that of $(x_n)$ i.e. $\lim(y_n)=\lim(x_n)$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your proof is incorrect but you are not far. Note that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ is only true for $n \geq N$, so you cannot apply it for $|x_1 - x|$ for instance. Therefore, you can control the terms $|x_m - x|$ like that for $N \leq m \leq n$, but you have to find some other argument for the first terms of the sum.
